# What does l_i_version in an ext4 inode actually do?

Tags: ext4

Trying to get behind the internals and secrets related to understanding ext4 I was reading on the [ext4.wiki](https://ext4.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Ext4_Disk_Layout). The author(s) did their best to show the structures used (such as the layout/struct of an ext4_inode) yet somtimes it seems they run out of ideas.

Looking up what `l_i_version` is used for I found this:

> l_i_version   Version (High 32-bits of the i_generation field?)

Later in the same `struct ext4_inode` appears also a field:

```
__le32  i_version_hi;   /* high 32 bits for 64-bit version */
```

which seems then to be the high 32 bits to the yet already high 32bits.

Can anybody shade a light on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[don_crissti](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/22142/don-crissti) found the original [patch submission](https://lkml.org/lkml/2007/10/25/283) for the extension of inode versions to 64 bits, which explains the use of these fields:

```
inode->i_version = le32_to_cpu(raw_inode->i_disk_version);
if (EXT4_INODE_SIZE(inode->i_sb) > EXT4_GOOD_OLD_INODE_SIZE) {
    if (EXT4_FITS_IN_INODE(raw_inode, ei, i_version_hi))
        inode->i_version |=
        (__u64)(le32_to_cpu(raw_inode->i_version_hi)) << 32;
}
```

`i_disk_version` is a [macro for `l_i_version`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/ext4/ext4.h#L886) (on Linux); this provides the low 32 bits of the inode version. If the inode size is larger, `i_version_hi` provides the high 32 bits.

`i_version` is the inode version, which is incremented every time the inode is modified (see [`mount(8)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/mount.8.html#FILESYSTEM-INDEPENDENT_MOUNT%C2%A0OPTIONS).